# LIBGDX how to load md2 format

Tags: libgdx

Im trying to import a md2 model in my libgdx game, but I can't find a good tutorial for it.

It seems like on internet, the only good link, refer to a broken links :
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/MD2_Keyframe_Animation

they said to use "KeyframeModelViewer", when I click on it, the link is broken.

Do you have another solution for me ? thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libgdx-users wiki is old and not up to date. If you're not using animations, there is no reason to use MD2 (instead use FBX). If you are using animations, keyframed animation is currently (nightly builds) not supported (and probably not worth using). Instead you can use GPU skinning and the FBX file format.

If you use fbx-conv (https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv) animations (including skinning) is automatically converted to the for libgdx readable G3DB or G3DJ file format. See also: http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/. The libgdx tests includes examples on how to use those: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d.